# FileSystemObject - new object added to dir during the middle of a For loop

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I have a VBA function that creates a FileSystemObject instance, and uses it to read the contents of a directory and perform some stuff based on conditional logic.

In the function, I use a loop that reads the contents of the dir. **My question is:** What happens when a new file is added to the dir *after the loop has been opened but before it is closed*? Does the operating system know to include this file in the collection of files? Or is a 'snapshot' of sorts taken of the dir when the loop is opened, causing the newly-added file to be overlooked?

Please correct me on any improper terminology I may have used above.

My code is below:

```
Function fn_FileCheckType()

    'load INI data
    fn_ReadINI

    'does filename end with .xls or .xlsx?
        'read files from iDumpFolder
        Dim fs          As Object
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim objFolder   As Object
        Set objFolder = fs.GetFolder(iDumpFolder)
        Dim objFile     As Object

        For Each objFile In objFolder.files

            If (objFile.Name Like "*.xls" Or objFile.Name Like "*.xlsx") Then
                'do nothing
                Debug.Print objFile.Name & " is valid."
            Else
                'copy to invalid file archive and delete from inbox
                objFile.Copy (iInvalidArchive & "\" & objFile.Name)
                MsgBox (objFile.Name & " is not saved as .xls or .xlsx. Please modify and re-import.")
                objFile.Delete
            End If

        Next 'objFile

    'Cleanup
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: This is very easy to test - put a breakpoint in your loop and while the code is paused, add a file to the folder. Does it get processed?  In any case, it's generally not a good idea to alter a collection while at the same time iterating over it - better to first collect all the file names (eg in a Collection object or an array) and then process the files.

Comment: Thanks - will follow your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The following VBA code indicates that the `.Files` collection is a "snapshot" of the files in a folder at the moment that the collection is referenced. Before running the code I placed two files in the test folder: `b.txt` and `c.txt`. The `Debug.Assert` statement suspends the code immediately after entering the loop for the first time. While paused, I added the files `a.txt` and `d.txt` and then hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to resume execution. The code only lists the two files that were originally in the folder.

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilesCollectionTest()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, objFolder As Folder, objFile As File, i As Long
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\__tmp\zzzTest")
    i = 1
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Debug.Assert i > 1
        Debug.Print objFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your example written `objFolder.files` is re-evaluated on every iteration and would thus pick up any change. But, I was a little surprised to see that if you so something like

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim files, f
Set files = fso.GetFolder("C:\~\My test Folder").files

For Each f In files
    debug.print f.name
Next f

Debug.Print   ' break point here
Debug.Print
```

That even if you are not in the loop `Files` is refreshed. I put a breakpoint on the firs `Print` after the loop, added a file to my folder then hit <kbd>F8</kbd>, and `Files` updated to the right file count.

Comment: Interestingly enough, my test suggests that the `.Files` collection is *not* re-evaluated on each iteration. See my answer for details.

Comment: @GordThompson Interesting indeed. You know what I had done, which seemed to influence things, is that I had `files` expanded in the Locals window. I think that was forcing a re-evaluation.